# Can you completely disable members on the frontend?

Tags: members, performance, optimization

Each time a template is loaded in ExpressionEngine is goes through a couple of member related tasks (as far as I can see):-

1. Is this user in a blacklist? `Addons_model::module_installed()`
2. Grab the current session data `EE_Session::fetch_session_data()`
3. Get the information about the current member `EE_Session::_do_member_query()`
4. Update the session information with this new visit `EE_Session::update_session()`
5. Fetch the CSRF token `Csrf_database::fetch_token()`

I found the above behaviour in the output, so perhaps they don't even run the above processes for the normal guest user.

But assuming a couple or all of them do - it seems quite heavy handed for a site that doesn't require memberships.

Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: Which version? 2.8.1?

Comment: Yes sorry. I should have clarified.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is, basically, no but it should not matter too much.

You **can** remove/uninstall the Members module but it does not actually remove most of the member related tables and it doesn't control most of the queries which are sprinkled throughout core code and do not appear to be controlled by any global setting.

You also cannot disable sessions in EE, which is what most of what you are seeing is actually setting up. Even if there were a way to disable sessions, likely many add-ons would fail to work because many, many extensions hook into the sessions_start or sessions_end [hooks](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/global/session/index.html) and use them to do things completely unrelated to sessions.

However, I doubt that the performance penalty for these queries is very high -- in all likelihood if there are no members in the system then there is very little or no data to be returned by all of the Member related queries.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can disable any member related functionality site-wide, but you can definitely disable it on the channel entries level, with something like this:

`{exp:channel:entries disable="member_data"}`

This should remove querying additional member related data that you are not using in your channels.

See: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#disable